# Determine P {X > Y }: Joint random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Despite the numerous questions on this topic I still seem to struggle at setting proper limits for my integrals.

I am given the following function:

$72x^2y(1-x)(y-1), 0<x<1,0<y<1$

and I am asked to find P{X > Y}

I figure that I simply need the following:

$    P(X > Y)= 72\int_0^1 \int_0^x [x^2y^2 - x^2y -x^3y^2 + x^3y ] dydx$

However, that gets me a negative value: -0.62857143

That value is logically illogical, as a probability shouldn't be negative. Are my limits wrong? It would seem logical to set the $y$ on [0,x], as I am looking for the area between the curves when $y$ is *below* $x$.

Comment: Your limits are right, but the density is not a density at all. $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 72x^2y(1-x)(y-1)\,dx\,dy = -1$$. So change sign from the very beginning.

Comment: Are you sure your density is OK? If $0<x,y<1$, all the factors of the density are nonnegative, except $y-1$, so the density is also negative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake or a typo in your density function (which *can't* be negative), its probably
$$
72x^2y(1-x)\color{red}{(1-y)}, \quad0<x<1,\quad0<y<1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I'll send a message to my teacher and see whether there was a typo in the assignment.

Comment: Upon inquiry, it appears there was indeed a typo. My professor has now corrected the function, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Devilius You are very welcome!